# TortoiseSVN: files are marked in the log as both 'modified' and 'added'

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've committed some changes into a repository. Some files have been added, others have been modified. After that all modified files have both **Modified** and **Added** actions in the log.

[image]

How can it be and what am I missing?

(Tried to find anything about this but found nothing.)

(**svn log** command shows only 'M' for all such files.)

Thanks.

Comment: I see nothing wrong, sure you can have modified and added files. Look in the file list here you see which files have which status

Comment: The problem is that the upper file on the screenshot has both statuses at the same time. That's what my question is about. I'm sure that a file may be either added or modified, but not both. Apparently I don't understand something or there's a bug in TortoiseSVN as SVN CLI shows only 'M'.

Comment: No, this indicates the operations for all files, so you modified files and added new ones

Comment: Got it: the Actions column in TortoiseSVN is about the entire revision whereas the SVN 'log' command shows only the status of the file in question. This difference caused my misunderstanding. Thank you.